# How to launch python in Visual Studio Code with superuser permission or root permission? (i.e. using sudo command)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, sudo

To execute my python program from the command line, I use `sudo python myProgram.py` because my program requires root privileges.

To execute the same from Visual Studio Code IDE, I tried prefixing the `pythonPath` variable in launch.json file with the `sudo` command but I get the following error:

> **Error: spawn sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 ENOENT**

Here is my task configuration

```
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "pythonPath": "sudo /usr/local/bin/python3",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "env": {},
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "debugOptions": [
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the below configuration now am able to execute with sudo privilege

Sudo in debugOptions and
"console": "externalTerminal",

Here is the complete configuration

```
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput",
            "Sudo"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 12):

There is now a [`sudo`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_sudo) option for Python debug configurations:

> When set to `true` and used with `"console": "externalTerminal"`, allows for debugging apps that require elevation. Using an external console is necessary to capture the password.

It is `false` by default, so you need to add it to your *launch.json* and set it to `true`:

```json
{
    "name": "run-python-script-with-sudo",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "program": "/path/to/script.py",
    "console": "externalTerminal",
    "sudo": true
}
```

Do note that it will use the same Python interpreter you configured for your workspace. To override that and set a different Python interpreter, add the [`python`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_python) option:

> To use a different interpreter, specify its path instead in the
> `python` property of a debug configuration.