# How can I debug Go file in VS Code with root privileges?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, delve

How can I force Delve in VS Code to use root privileges?

I'm trying to debug go file that involves gopacket/pcap:

```
hndl, err := pcapgo.NewEthernetHandle(ifname)
// err == "couldn't open packet socket: operation not permitted"
```

Launching same program using `sudo` doesn't trigger error.

I've tried several methods:

1. Launch `sudo code .` It warns that it is not recommended. Plus there are issues to use dlv in this mode as environment variables are messed up.
2. Using this guide https://fatdragon.me/blog/2020/06/debug-golang-vs-code-linux-root. However `"go.alternateTools"` seems to know nothing about "dlv": `Property dlv is not allowed.` Probably something is missing in guide.
3. Search for `.vscode/launch.json` config property that allows to sudo. VSC allows to do such for [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144580/how-to-launch-python-in-visual-studio-code-with-superuser-permission-or-root-per), but not for Go.

Is there any trivial way to launch debugger with root privileges?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- VSCode 1.48.0
- Go 1.13.4
- Delve 1.4.0

Comment: Is there any reason you insist on using dlv _inside_ vscode? Why not start dlv directly as root?

Comment: Did you try the Go extension from Google team in VS code? It works decently well for even complex programs. You might face issues in viewing data for variables. https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

Comment: As a workaround I use GoLand that has checkbox "Run with sudo". Nice and easy. Looking for same simple solution for VSC. Opened feature request https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/558

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Update May 2022

[Debugging programs and tests as root](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#debugging-programs-and-tests-as-root) in the documentation of the VSCode Go addon has been updated accordingly with task and launch configuration examples to not only debug programs but also tests as root.

#### Old

Debugging Go programs and tests that require root privileges using VSCode has been sore for a long time. As of VSCode version 1.65.0 I noticed a new experimental launch option `"asRoot": "true"`  that needs to be combined with `"console": "integratedTerminal"`.

For instance, in your `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Test/dbg pkg as root",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "asRoot": true,
        },
    ]
}
```

When launching this configuration by pressing F5, a new debug terminal session opens (or might get reused) and the following command executed:

```bash
/usr/bin/env GOPATH=/home/foobar/go /usr/bin/sudo /home/foobar/go/bin/dlv dap --check-go-version=false --client-addr=:41945
```

This now automatically inserts the `sudo` command before `dlv` itself, so this needs to be launched into an internal or external interactive **terminal** (and thus does not work in the internal console). After authenticating to sudo, VSCode switches back to the debug console view and you are good to go.

This now avoids having to fiddle around with remapping the `dlv` command in your workspace to a wrapper shell script.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, a good solution.

Comment: Don't thank me, please thank the good soul(s) that finally implemented it in VSCode.