# VS Code debugging as root user

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have VS Code running on macOS connecting to a linux box where I am doing Go development. I am connecting via a user that has sudo privileges on the linux host. The root account is disabled on the remote host.

The application I am writing needs to run with root privileges. Is there a way to set vscode to elevate privileges when debugging the application? Or do I need to enable the root account for software development purposes?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md There doesn't seem to be a setting for your case yet. Open an issue there so that you can discuss with the authors.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the answer I received from the vs code developer team. This isn’t a feature and it will never be a feature.

> In order to debug as a root, the debugger (dlv) must run as a root.
> Nether dlv, nor this extension aims to offer privilege escalation
> solutions. In remote debugging, dlv on the remote machine is
> externally managed, not by this extension, so it's out of scope.
> Moreover, this extension just communicates with the dlv on the remote
> host with DAP, which is not designed for security. So I am afraid this
> extension is not the right layer for privilege escalation. To debug as
> a root, as you already know, run dlv on the remote machine as a root
> (you may also need to set --only-same-user=false if the remote host is
> Linux) but protect access to the dlv server & the remote machine
> appropriately using proven security technologies. For local debugging,
> this is tracked in #558. But, I want to emphasize that debugging as a
> root still needs to be done with great care.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I was able to run my tests as root for Python development. This should work for most Visual Studio Code debug environments on MacOS and Linux.

First run the debugger and let the `Debug Console` (Terminal) start up. Stop debugger if needed. In the same `Debug Console` window type `sudo su` -> [Enter]. Once you log in as root via password prompt, the `Debug Console` is running as root and the next time you run, the code will be run as root.

Note: At the time of creating this doc, the VSCode `Restart` debugger command creates a new console so this cannot which resets the session so it cannot be used; To re-test, you need to stop and than restart.

If you close the debug console, you will need to repeat the above steps.

Comment: Tks, I was able to do almost same, but using SSH remote debugging extension.

Comment: The Q mentions Go development, not] python.

Comment: @TheDiveO - Thanks. I'll amend my post.

Comment: `sudo su
error CS0726: 'su' is not a valid format specifier` for C#

Comment: `sudo su` looks wrong, I would expect `sudo` but not any `su` then again.

Comment: @TheDiveO - No, this is correct. `sudo su` will change the context for the terminal to root for the terminal session. Just typing `sudo` without anything following will error out as sudo requires a command.

Comment: @korval - You need to execute `sudo su` in the terminal window not in your source file. I've clarified this in my doc.

Comment: Attempted this with vs code c/c++ debugger, but it seems the vs code debugger UI couldn't connect to the process.

Comment: @Superman.Lopez - Are you using windows? I don't think that Windows has a `su` equivalent.

Comment: No, this is on Linux.  I can move the shell to root as you instruct without an issue, but the debugger UI seems to wait for the process forever.  It just doesn't connect.

Comment: @Superman.Lopez - Very strange. I've never done any .net on Linux besides maintaining websites. You might want to raise a bug with Microsoft for the c/c++ debugger in VSCode Linux.

Answer (score 3):

While not the exact same environment, I suppose that the needed underlying functionality of needing root to debug, test, and run your code from VSCode is the same as in this answer to [How can I debug Go file in VS Code with root privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71402050) here.

The gist: VSCode version 1.65.0 has a new experimental launch option `"asRoot": "true"`, use it with `"console": "integratedTerminal"`.

For instance, in your `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Test/dbg pkg as root",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "asRoot": true,
        },
    ]
}
```

When launching this configuration by pressing F5, a new debug terminal session opens (or might get reused) and the following command executed, needing `sudo` (which you mentioned you do have rights to use):

```sh
/usr/bin/env GOPATH=/home/foobar/go /usr/bin/sudo /home/foobar/go/bin/dlv dap --check-go-version=false --client-addr=:41945
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works well for me in remote debugging

Comment: 1.78.1 VSCode not working

Answer (score 1):

```
"program": "sudo ${workspaceFolder}/build/src/zhub",
```

Works for me, C++