# Must be run as administrartor-python

Tags: python

I got this error- I'm a noob because I'm self-taught mostly, nvm

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 294, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator
```

my code is just for learning about the keyboard library

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        print("yep a!")
```

Comment: if you want answers, start by adding your code and some information about it.

Answer (score 2):

I supposed that you are running your script on a MacOS. If you would like to record keyboard events without application, you will need to grant administrator privilege to your script, by doing the following.

```
sudo python your-script.py
```

Comment: im running on visual studio code not idle.

Comment: You will need to modify your launch settings in that case. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144580/how-to-launch-python-in-visual-studio-code-with-superuser-permission-or-root-per) is a good example.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what I should do with that json, but why did code use to word until now.

Comment: You can learn more about the `launch.json` file [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).

Comment: i mostly fixed the problem, so i dont want to bother fixing anymore, it is the path of python3 and pip3, i nearnly broke my os but thank you very much